# How to access the NTFS filesystem on CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, ntfs

i tried:

```
mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdc1
```

but command not found, and the locate command shows nothing for mkfs.ntfs.

I tried gparted but the ntfs is hidden...Can anybody help to me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
   sudo yum install ntfsprogs
   sudo yum install ntfs-3g
```

Comment: ntfsprogs adds mkfs.ntfs in centos 7/8 this was missing; ntfs-3g was installed.

Answer (score 1):

**-  EPEL repository**

```
yum -y install epel-release
```

**- Install ntfs-3g**

```
yum -y install ntfs-3g
```

**- Update Grub**

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Answer (score -3):

The issue is not really a format disk problem - it is more of a "how to I access nfs".

Assuming that you are using Ubuntu or Debian then you simple need to add the nfs file system options - which are not installed by default.

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

At this point - your **mkfs** should work as well as **gparted**

I hope this works well for you.

Comment: apt-get not found...may be i have to install firstly other?

Comment: sudo yum install ntfs-3g works...but i dont have ntfs

Comment: CentOS does not use apt-get.